# Magento - Select the cms pages of the current store

Tags: magento

I use this collecion to select the cms pages

```
    $collection = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('is_active',1)
        ->addFieldToFilter('identifier',array(array('nin'=>array('no-route','enable-cookies'))));
```

How can I change it to select **only** the cms pages of the current store ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the code below: ->addStoreFilter($store,$withAdmin)

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()
              ->addStoreFilter($storeId)// You have to provide a store id or Mage_Core_Model_Store Object @see class Mage_Cms_Model_Mysql4_Page_Collection
              ->addFieldToFilter('is_active',1)
              ->addFieldToFilter('identifier',array(array('nin'=>array('no-route','enable-cookies'))));
```

Comment: Do you know how can I order the results by title ?
I have tried `->addAttributeToSort('title', 'ASC');` but it don't works !

Comment: try this but not tested: ->addOrder('title', 'ASC')

Answer (score 2):

If you do not need filters try this:

```
$cmsPage = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->setStore(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load('faq-and-help', 'identifier');
```